# Download folders from ftp server using PDI

Tags: regex, pentaho, pdi

I am trying to download entire folders using `'Get a file with ftp'` step. Does this step only download files? I also tried regular expression to match folders. 
I have used the following regular expression for folders:
`^[a-zA-Z0-9]$`

Also, it's only downloading the `.txt files`. I have used the following regular expression for files:
`*\.(txt|jpg|gif|pdf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx)`

Note: I want to download entire folders in the specified directory but I am also facing issues with downloading only files.

Comment: Hi Nawaz, This question might sound weird to you but I will still ask. Why am I not getting any reply to my question?

Comment: What is PDI? What issues are you facing? Any errors?

Comment: You're not getting any replies because you used the wrong tag. People who are interested in regex-related questions look for the [tag:regex] tag.  The [tag:qregularexpression] tag applies to one specific **flavor** of regex, and one of the least popular ones at that.

Comment: @Alan Moore: I have modified the tags to make it more relevant to the question asked.                                                                                      PDI is a data integration tool for developing ETL packages.

Comment: If you do want to get all of the files, just use `*.*` as the regexp wildcard and you should get all of the files. Regarding sub-folders, I am not sure that the step is supposed to download sub-folders.

Comment: @YuvalHerziger: The regular expression to get all types of files is **.*\.***, but I want the entire folder to be copied to the target location. Is there any regular expression download the folders?